# Problema con edición gráfica de formulario en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net

Me sucedió algo curioso. Uso la versión 4.8.04 de Visual Studio Community 2019 y cloné un proyecto que tenía en Github. Lo compilo y no me da ningún error, funciona normal. Sin embargo, al tratar de editar cualquier formulario visualmente, este me muestra solo su código. No me permite verlo de forma gráfica. ¿Es posible corregir esto?

Ya he intentado verla con F7, pero no cambia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te sucedió es que te encuentras en la vista de carpetas. El editor te lo dice en el título del Explorador de soluciones. Te lo señalé con un rectángulo naranja.

[image: Imagen del autor de la pregunta con indicaciones]

Para volver a la vista de solución:

1. Presionar el botón al lado de la casita, también te lo señalé, con color celeste. Verás algo así:

[image: Ejemplo de elección de vistas]

2. Selecciona la solución. En mi caso, en el proyecto que tomé de ejemplo ya se encuentra en dicha vista y aparece en negrita.

Con ese procedimiento el IDE debería funcionar como siempre.

Si por algún motivo quieres cambiar de vistas, el procedimiento es el mismo, solo que eligiendo una opción diferente

Comment: Muchas gracias Mateo, saludos desde Colombia.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me paso lo mismo y era porque en la ventana de código del formulario cree una clase antes de la clase del formulario.
Colocando esa clase al final del código se recuperó la ventana de diseño del formulario